# Rails find_by_sql not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m trying to do execute find_by_sql Rails method and it´s not working.

Query:

```
@boats = Boat.find_by_sql(["SELECT * 
                                FROM boats b, ports p
                                WHERE p.name = ? 
                                AND b.port_id = p.id", port])
puts @boats.inspect
```

Query returns two elements, however it´s the same element twice [id=1 and id=1]. If I run the query in the database then I got two different results [id=1 and id=2]

Comment: "I got two different results [id=1 and id=1]" - typo?

Comment: Yes, Chowlett. Sorry. In rails I get same result twice. In mysql I get two different ids which is correct.

Comment: why are you using a `find_by_sql` here? this should be a relation between boats and ports!

Comment: This is just a simple example. The query will be quite more complex... and I read for complex queries it´s recommended to use this method.

Comment: You seem to be selecting all columns of both the boats table and the ports table in order to create a set of Boat objects. Perhaps you mean to select b.*?

Comment: You are a magician David! It works!! Stupid detail from my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be selecting all columns of both the boats table and the ports table in order to create a set of Boat objects. Perhaps you mean to select b.*?